# How to debug a function which is under a template string

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I worked with an API link which shows fakeproducts like an ecommerce website. When I am trying to debug the function addToCart which is called under a template string. It's not breaking on that point. Help me with how to debug it.

Website link: https://inspiring-payne-594c82.netlify.app/

I added the specific code where my issue is.

```
// show all product in UI 
const showProducts = (products) => {
  products.forEach(product => {
    const image = product.image;
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("product");
    div.innerHTML = `<div class="single-product">
      <div>
    <img class="product-image" src=${image}></img>
      </div>
      <h3>${product.title}</h3>
      <p>Category: ${product.category}</p>
      <h2>Price: $ ${product.price}</h2>
      <button onclick="addToCart(${product.id}, ${product.price})" id="addToCart-btn" class="buy-now btn btn-success">add to cart</button>
      <button id="details-btn" class="btn btn-danger">Details</button></div>
      `;
    document.getElementById("all-products").appendChild(div);
  })
};
```

Comment: Where are you adding the breakpoint?

Comment: here is the full code link: https://github.com/Programming-Hero-Web-Course4/ranga-store-fix-TechSinkV1      adding breakpoint on this line: <button onclick="addToCart(${product.id}, ${product.price})" id="addToCart-btn" class="buy-now btn btn-success">add to cart</button>

Comment: You have lots of buttons with the same id: `addToCart-btn`. Ids need to be unique. Perhaps use a class.

Comment: I used bootstrap format on declaring button. It's default bootstrap code. All of the id's are unique.

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint needs to be set where the function is defined, not where it's passed to the button tag. The github link you provided is broken, but going by the source of the website you linked to:

```js
let count = 0;
const addToCart = (id, price) => {
  count = count + 1; // <==== breakpoint goes here
  updatePrice("price", price);

  updateTaxAndCharge();
  document.getElementById("total-Products").innerText = count;
};
```